# Mocha, Chai & Sinon: Checking internal working of an API

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai-http

Let's suppose I have a POST endpoint `/user/:id` and this endpoint, internally calls a function `getUserData(id)` and then returns the result to the caller, which in-turn returns the output, after `JSON.stringify()`ing.

Now, I need to ensure that `getUserData(id)` is called, for at-least once. How can I stub / spy `getUserData(id)` function, when I am using `chai-http` to make a post request to the server? Is it even a correct approach?

Comment: usually you just include the controller in a separate test and spy,stub & mock things so you can test the controller. API testing is less complex you just send request and run test against the result. Take a look at the official documentation it should provide enough information to  write the test.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the tutorial from https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai down to a barebones `server` and `test` that you can use to do a basic API test.

As Mr.Phoenix said, you don't need to get too deep into the nitty gritty of your `handler`, just pass some data to your endpoint and check the result against what you expect to get.

Here are 2 files you can use to do this test:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()



app.get('/material',(req, res)=>{
  res.json([])
  //res.json(['stone', 'wood'])
})

function getUserData(id){
  return 42
}

const port = 3031

app.listen(port, function(err){
  console.log("Listening on port: " + port)
})
module.exports = app
```

**test.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'
// const Material = require('./materials') // conroller
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const server = require('./index')
const should = chai.should()


chai.use(chaiHttp)



describe('/GET material', () => {
  it('it should get all the materials', (done)=>{
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/material')
    .end((err, res) => {
      res.should.have.status(200)
      res.body.should.be.a('array')
      res.body.length.should.be.eql(0) // start empty
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I do want to get into the nitty gritty? I am writing separate tests for the controller, as suggested by @Mr.Phoenix